# Custom i2c with Arduino UNO

Tags: arduino, transistors, i2c, pullup, diy

For educational purposes, I would like to write my own **i2c** protocol. Is it possible to write a custom **i2c** library to communicate using regular ports, or should I use the **SCL** and **SDA** ports? Can I mimic **SDA** port by using an external transistor with pull-up resistor connected to digital pin?

Comment: The [NXP I2C specification](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/UM10204.pdf) was originally written before dedicated hardware was available. Bit-banging a GPIO is the original way it was done,

Comment: I was looking at a design where the I2C bus interface available to a FPGA was actually 2 output and 1 input pins, with a CPLD on the board connecting the 3 pins on the FPGA to the actual SCL and SDA signals connected to other I2C devices on the board. As per [I2C SCL from CPLD is push-pull rather than open-collector](https://gist.github.com/Chester-Gillon/27d9ed419a25ecb3c4358377da34924b#2-i2c-scl-from-cpld-is-push-pull-rather-than-open-collector) this lead to some restrictions on use of I2C.

Comment: Continued. If it helps [i2c_bit_banged.c](https://github.com/Chester-Gillon/fpga_sio/blob/main/software_tests/eclipse_project/source/i2c_probe/i2c_bit_banged.c) is the source code for the bit-banged driver which was created for the above board, which runs under Linux on a x86-64 processor rather than an Arduino. Given the relatively fast processor, the driver inserts the delays from the I2C spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible, yes, and has been done many times already.

It can be done with GPIO ports.

You can mimic SDA port with an external transistor and a pull-up, but usually nobody does it because it can be done without the external transistor by simply using the GPIO ports. No external hardware at all, only the pull-up resistors that are needed anyway.

What you seem to be trying to do is just called software bit-banged I2C interface.

Since you tagged "Arduino", I would be very surprised if the Arduino framework does not already have a software based I2C implementation built-in you can simply use so you don't even have to write it yourself.

Edit: Just confirmed, Arduino comes with "SoftWire" library .

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Yes, I know that Arduino has native I2C library. I'd like to write a custom one for better understanding. Also I'm planing to program chips and to do that I'd like to try it first on Arduino board.

Comment: @AntonTsvayer Arduino has both a native I2C library that uses the I2C hardware and it also has a software bit-bang library which you want to replicate. Feel free to reinvent the wheel, you can use the SoftWire as a base to learn or write your own.